# MemoryStream.CopyTo Not working

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, io

```
TiffBitmapDecoder decoder = new TiffBitmapDecoder(imageStreamSource, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);

using (MemoryStream allFrameStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    foreach (BitmapFrame frame in decoder.Frames)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms= new MemoryStream())
        {
            JpegBitmapEncoder enc = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
            enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(frame));
            enc.Save(ms);
            ms.CopyTo(allFrameStream);
        }
    }

    Document documentPDF = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(documentPDF, allFrameStream);
}
```

Always allFrameStream's `Length=0`. But each iteration I could see `ms.Length=989548`. What is the error in my code. why `ms.CopyTo(allFrameStream)` is not working?

Comment: Where are you looking at allFrameStream.Length? The code you've shown never uses the stream you're copying to.

Comment: @JonSkeet, after for each loop. When I debug i see at `PdfWriter.GetInstance`, allFrameStream.Length=0 in quick watch window

Comment: @JonSkeet, basically I am trying to read multiple page TIFF image and coverting to pdf using iTextSharp

Comment: @Billa this is not the right way to convert multiple TIFF to PDF.  Please check this article http://atashbahar.com/post/Converting-Multipage-TIFF-image-to-PDF.aspx

Answer (score 40):

Reset `Position` of `ms` to 0 after you fill it:

```
enc.Save(ms);
ms.Position = 0;
ms.CopyTo(allFrameStream);
```

From [`Stream.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Copying begins at the current position in the current stream

Comment: How is this is a thing? why doesnt the CopyTo include the ms.position = 0 !?

Comment: @JpHouten that's how streams work. Every read and write starts from the current position. Of course there are some exceptions. For example [ToArray()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray(v=vs.110).aspx) on the MemoryStream works regardless of current position

Comment: It feels as if they could have made it so that it wouldn't give a "index out of range" exception if you do not use the position = 0; personally I would have gone with a different method, for example an .Add function

Answer (score 6):

Try executing `allFrameStream.Position = 0;` just before writing to the PDF.

Answer (score 6):

After writing to `ms`, the position of `ms` is at its end. You have to seek to the beginning of the stream, e.g. with:

```
ms.Seek(0,System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

After that `ms.CopyTo` is working correctly.